# Flex Playing Media

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, mxml

Is it possible to play mpeg, avi, divx or other video types in Flex or do they need to be converted?

I've looked around and I can only find that flv files are supported.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:

From "Programming Flex 3" (O'Reilly), p. 295:

> Flash Player supports four video codecs: H.264, On2 VP6, Sorenson Spark and Screen. Unless you have existing encoded Flash video, the H.264 codec will be optimal, as it currently has the best support for high-quality video playback

To display video that is encoded as any of the above, the Flex framework uses the `VideoDisplay` component which expects a flv file as an argument.

The `VideoDisplay` component is in the Flex language reference [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/VideoDisplay.html) and for completeness, have a look at the [Adobe forum thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/474961) linked to from [Tanmay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524581/flex-playing-media/1524612#1524612).

Answer (score 0):

no, by flash alone no. you either have to convert them in flv or stream them somehow in flv format.

Answer (score 0):

This question was discussed in Adobe forum

See

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/474961